# How to set Multiple AlarmManager on list Item?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have the problem with my code.
I have list with date and time. I get all date and time from SQLite in for loop. Now when i run program AlarmManager is not triggered on every date and time. Last added alarm only received.
Here i have the code:

```
            private void setAlarm() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DbHandler dbHandler =new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
            list_alarm = dbHandler.getDateOnly();
            Log.d("00000", list_alarm.size()+"");
            if(list_alarm.size() > 0){
                for(int i=0;i<list_alarm.size();i++){
                    String dat = list_alarm.get(i).getTaskDate();
                    String pat = list_alarm.get(i).getTaskTime();
                    String strDnT = dat+" "+pat;
                    SimpleDateFormat format;
                    Date date1;
                    long d;
                    format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                    try {
                        date1 = (Date)format.parse(strDnT);
                        d = date1.getTime();
                        Intent k = new Intent(Create_Task.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), RQS_1, k, 0);
                        AlarmManager managers = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        managers.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, d, intent);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }else{
                Log.d("List : ", "Not having any list");
            }

        }
```

Thanks in Advance. I hope You Understand my Question.

Comment: did you try setting alaram one by one?#

Comment: ya I do that but nothing happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stated in android doc.

**If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.**

I believe you need to set the timing one by one: I mean when alarm is invoked with T1 then set for T2. when T2 is finished then set T3...

Comment: Means You want to say that, I have to make array of **AlarmManager**...??